# How do I initialize Flickity with HTML in Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-6, flickity

I am using the [Flickity library](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/#getting-started).

This is my HTML:

```
<section class="controls-inside controls-light p-0" data-flickity='{ "imagesLoaded": true, "wrapAround": true }'>
```

It works well on the first load, which creates this HTML:

```
<section class="controls-inside controls-light p-0 flickity-enabled is-draggable" data-flickity="{ "imagesLoaded": true, "wrapAround": true }" tabindex="0">
```

But once I navigate to any other page and try to go back to the homepage (where this code is), it generates just the first code at the top (i.e. the uninitialized version).

This is currently my `TL` code:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

So given that I am using HTML initialization, how do I do handle this with TL?

**Edit 1**

I am also open to initializing Flickity via JS if it hasn't been initialized via HTML. Either way is fine by me so it works.

**Edit 2**

In my `application.js`, I now have the following:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  var Flickity = require('flickity');
  var flkty = new Flickity( 'section[data-flickity]', {
      imagesLoaded: true,
      wrapAround: true,
  });
})
```

This kinda works. What happens is when I try to navigate to another page and go back to the one that has the slider, I can see that it loads twice. As in, it loads the slider initially and I see it then midway during loading bar progress the entire page refreshes again. So it feels like it is doing twice the work. I just want it loaded once.

It also produces the following errors in my Browser Console.

On 1st load of the page:

```
flickity.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined
    at new Flickity (flickity.js:57)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.js:43)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4490)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
Flickity @ flickity.js:57
(anonymous) @ application.js:43
dispatch @ jquery.js:4670
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4490
./node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch @ turbolinks.js:75
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.js:994
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.js:948
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.js:872
flickity.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined
    at new Flickity (flickity.js:57)
    at utils.js:217
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at utils.js:201
```

If I clear the errors from my console, navigate away and come back, this is the only error in my console on that second page load:

```
flickity.js:47 Bad element for Flickity: section[data-flickity]
```

What could be causing these errors and how do I fix it?

**Edit 3**

In my `application.js`, I included Flickity accordingly.

```
import '../src/flickity.pkgd.min'
```

Also, my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.2-2",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "data-confirm-modal": "^1.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "flickity": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "local-time": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

**Edit 4**

Here is what my `application.js` looks like:

```
import '../src/flickity.pkgd.min'

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  var Flickity = require('flickity');
  var flkty = new Flickity( 'section[data-flickity]', {
      imagesLoaded: true,
      wrapAround: true,
  });
})
```

Here is the error I get on the first page load in my JS console.

[image: first-load-errors-flickity]

**Edit 5**

Everything is more or less completely fixed, but I am still seeing a double reload whenever I go back to a page that was previously loaded with Flickity.

For example consider the following flow:

- Go to `home page` with Flickity (load once)
- Go to `Article#New` without Flickity (load once and Flickity doesn't load or throw JS error per latest update).
- Go back to `home page` with Flickity (it starts to load and about 1/4 or 1/3 way through that initial page load it does a complete page refresh and loads the entire page). That page refresh is noticeable because it happens about 1 - 2 seconds after the page starts loading.

I initially thought it was because I am initializing Flickity twice, i.e. once with the JS in the answer below and once via HTML like so:

```
<section id="featured-header" class="controls-inside controls-light p-0" data-flickity='{ "imagesLoaded": true, "wrapAround": true }'>
```

So I swapped the JS selector for the `id` of this tag and removed the HTML initialization of `data-flickity` but it still does the same behavior. i.e. I tested this code instead:

```
<section id="featured-header" class="controls-inside controls-light p-0">
```

So that leads me to believe it is something to do with the JS.

By the way, it seems that it actually just reloads that `section[data-flickity]` not necessarily the whole page. It also doesn't reload any other page when I navigate through various links. This only happens for the `section[data-flickity]` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the JS file that you have in your app `src` directory and install it using NPM

```
npm install flickity
```

Then, require Flickity CSS file in **application.css**

```
*= require flickity.css
```

Then, in you JS file you can initialize Flickity on `turbolinks:load` as you done for tooltip and popover.

```
import Flickity from 'flickity';

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
    if($('section[data-flickity]').length > 0) {
        var flkty = new Flickity( 'section[data-flickity]', {
            imagesLoaded: true,
            wrapAround: true,
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flickity is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.js:40)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4490)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872`

What could be causing this?

Comment: I added more info in my question with more debugging info for other stuff I have tried and those results.

Comment: Looks like `flickity` JS is not loaded. Can you share where and how you included this jS library?

Comment: I have added a way to solve the issue you added in **Edit 2** in my answer, please check that too.

Comment: I added how the JS library was included in the question. Refresh. I will try Edit 2 and report back.

Comment: I tried your **Edit 2** suggestions but they don't work :(

Comment: Can you try changing `import '../src/flickity.pkgd.min'` to `require('flickity')` in application.js file?

Comment: Did you installed this plugin through NPM? If yes, can you check for any console error when using `require('flickity')`?

Comment: Or if you have the JS file in `../src/` directory, can you try replacing `import` with `require` like `require('../src/flickity.pkgd.min')` and see whether it works?

Comment: I did both. I installed this plugin through NPM and when I just did that check via the console, this is the error I got: `require('flickity')
VM876:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`. I also have the JS file in `../src/` directory. When I tried that `require('../src/..')` it rendered fine but still produced the error in my console and still gave me the weird double refresh on the 2nd page load. aka that didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for you. The error `flickity.js:47 Bad element for Flickity: section[data-flickity]` will occur only if the element with the selector `section[data-flickity]` was not present. Can you check whether the element is present when you get this error?

Comment: I no longer get that specific error when `section[data-flickity]` is present on the page. But, I have updated my question with the error I now get on first page load.

Comment: The error that you added in **edit 4** will occur when loading the JS two or more times. As you have an `import` and `require` it is loading two times and causing this error. Please remove that `import` statement and follow the steps as in my updated answer and let me know whether it works.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have an `application.css`, only `application.scss`. So should I just do that necessary require there? i.e. `//= require flickity`, rather than `*= require flickity.css`?

Comment: Ok we have made a lot of progress. I did what I said and it works beautifully. I no longer see those errors in my console. But, when I go back to the page with Flickity I see the 2nd reload (although at this point that may be inevitable??). One other thing I am seeing is that when I navigate to any page that doesn't have `section[data-flickity]` it throws a `Bad element for Flickity: section[data-flickity]`. So how do I only trigger that TL on the specific pages where it is present? Or how do I only trigger it, if it is present on the page?

Comment: Btw, I hope you reply within 4 hours and we get it sorted out so I can apply this bounty to you because you deserve it. But it will expire within 4 hours, so let's try to get this done within that time!

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Ok that fixed that issue. I am still seeing the double loading/flickering when I go back to the previous page. In the interest of fairness, I have marked the answer accepted and awarded you the bounty. But, can you still help me with the double loading & flickering when I go back to the previous page? Want me to do a screen capture video of what I am seeing so you can understand better? Or do you get it?

Comment: I updated my question so you can see what I just tried and the results (it didn't work). I just updated that last edit with more details.